# Uploading model attributes with file using AWS SDK Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, form-for

What I'm looking to do is save my Song model attributes in the same form that I use to upload my mp3 files. I'm currently using the AWS-SDK gem.

As of now, I can successfully upload mp3 files to AWS. However, when I attempt to save the "song_title" and "album_id" attributes as well, the data does not save, but the file is uploaded.

Song attributes:

"id", "url", "name", "created_at", "updated_at", "album_id", "song_title"

songs_controller:

```
class Albums::SongsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_user_friendships

  def new
    @song = Song.new
  end

  def create
    # Make an object in your bucket for your song
    obj = S3_BUCKET.objects[params[:file].original_filename]

    # Upload the file
    obj.write(
      file: params[:file],
      acl: :public_read
    )

    # Create an object for the song
    @song = Song.new( 
        url: obj.public_url,
        name: obj.key
        )

    # Save the upload
    if @song.save
      redirect_to songs_path, success: 'File successfully uploaded'
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = 'There was an error'
      render :new
    end
  end

  def index
    @user_friendships = current_user.user_friendships.all
    @songs = Song.all
  end

  def song_params
    params.require(:song).permit(:id, :url, :name, :song_title, :album_id)
  end

  def set_user_friendships
    @user_friendships = current_user.user_friendships.all #this is here because of partial UGHHH
  end
end
```

songs/_upload_song.html.erb:

```
<p>Upload a song</p>

<%= form_tag songs_path, enctype: 'multipart/form-data' do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file  %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Upload song' %>
<% end %>
```

I tried changing the create method within the songs_controller to the following. (I added "song_params"):

```
  def create
    # Make an object in your bucket for your song
    obj = S3_BUCKET.objects[params[:file].original_filename]

    # Upload the file
    obj.write(
      file: params[:file],
      acl: :public_read
    )

    # Create an object for the song
    @song = Song.new(song_params,
        url: obj.public_url,
        name: obj.key
        )

    # Save the upload
    if @song.save
      redirect_to songs_path, success: 'File successfully uploaded'
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = 'There was an error'
      render :new
    end
  end
```

and the songs upload form to the following:

```
<p>Upload a song</p>

<%= form_tag songs_path, enctype: 'multipart/form-data' do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file  %>
  <%= text_field_tag :song_title  %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Upload song' %>
<% end %>
```

However, I get the following error:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: song
```

I suspect that the issue has something to do with the "form_tag" vs the "form_for" difference in forms.

After taking a look around, I found that the form_tag creates a basic form, and form_for creates a form for a model object.

So when changing the upload form to the one below:

```
<%= form_for Song.new, enctype: 'multipart/form-data' do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :file %>
  <%= f.file_field :file %>

  <%= f.label :song_title %>
  <%= f.text_field :song_title %>

  <%= f.label :album_id %>
  <%= f.number_field :album_id %>

  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `original_filename' for nil:NilClass
```

And the error references the following lines within the "create" method of my songs_controller:

```
obj = S3_BUCKET.objects[params[:file].original_filename]
```

I looked through the AWS-SDK documentation, but I find this information surprisingly hard to find.

Would someone mind shedding some light on how I would go about saving my Song attributes as well as uploading my Song mp3 file?

Comment: A nil class is just that, a nil class. It means there is no object, therefore `original_filename` does not exist.

Comment: Yes, that error occurs when I use the form_for form. However, with the form_tag form, the song file is uploaded correctly without the error.

Answer (score 0):

You created the method `song_params`, but I do not see you using it. You must explicitly set your object with the params returned by `song_params` in order to save the attributes upon `song.save`.

```
@song = Song.new(song_params)
```

Comment: Within the "create" method, I have 
    @song = Song.new(song_params,
        url: obj.public_url,
        name: obj.key
        )   However, that doesn't work. Any way to add "song_params" to the existing song instance variable?

Comment: Why are you passing in `id` in the permitted parameters?

Comment: I assumed it was required. However, even if I remove it, the problem remains.

Comment: The issue is not that I cannot save Song with the attributes I have created (without uploading the song file) or that I can't upload the file, but I cannot do both together. Can I add "song params" to the following code?    @song = Song.new( 
        url: obj.public_url,
        name: obj.key
        )

Comment: And how would I structure the form?

Comment: change `params[:file].original_file` to  `params[:song][:file].original_file`

Comment: When making the change, I get "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" with a reference to the line below: obj = S3_BUCKET.objects[params[:song][:file].original_file]

Comment: this is not an answer